# tesseract doesnt show any output when called via subprocess python

Tags: python, image-processing, tesseract

Im trying to read a captcha from from tesseract inside python using subprocess, but it gives out gibberish output as

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['tesseract', 'CAPT1.png','stdout','-l','eng','--oem 3','--psm 7','>>','nm.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
Out : (b' \n\x0c', None)
```

Tried decong still no luck :-

```
print (stdout.decode('utf-8'))
Out : ' \n\x0c'
```

Even pytesseract isnt giving any output:

```
import pytesseract
ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('CAPT1.png'), lang='eng', \
        config='eng --psm 7 --oem 3')
print (ocr)
Out :
```

Whereas the same tesseract when called from command line in linux gives correct output

```
tesseract CAPT1.png stdout -l eng --oem 3 --psm 7
Out: X8ZUZ4
```

Comment: In the first code snippets there is `'>>','nm.txt'` at the end of the parameters and e.g. `'--oem 3'` should be two distinct parameters. Maybe this confuses tesseract.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, doesnt work, still the same gibberish output in the nm.txt text file

Answer (score 1):

Solved by a hack , simply copied the command  in  a shell script and executed inside notebook as

!sh tes.sh